# How to make simple databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I just would like to make a simple dataBinding between a textbox field and a dataGridView control..
How can I make this?
[image]

With Winforms I would add a Databinding with this

```
 NameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Categories.Category_Product.ProductName");
```

But I'm trying to do this in wpf and I don't see how to make this..

Here's the code for the page.

```
 public partial class Categories : Window
{
    public Categories()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        DataTable dt = CATEGORIE_MANAGER.GetList(false);

        listViewListe.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        cbbParent.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;                                   
    }

}
```

How can I link the textBox with the ListViewListe? Should I use the dataContext? How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" 
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listViewListe, Path=SelectedItem}"
Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
```

Comment: <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" 
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listViewListe, Path=SelectedItem"}
Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"/> works Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your Xaml

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=NameTextBox,Path=SelectedItem.ProductName} />
```